# In a reverse proxy implementation, are the addresses still accessible outside the reverse proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy

My company is looking at creating a subdomain for content that's currently stored in a subfolder on the site.  As an SEO this decision makes my skin crawl.  Since the decision has been made to implement the subdomain (server architecture decision to move parts of the site to a cloud provider), I would like to have IT implement a reverse proxy so we don't have to 301 the whole content base to a fresh subdomain.

One of the main objections IT has is that if we implement he reverse proxy, and there are issues with content or webpage functionality, the cloud provider will point to the reverse proxy as the issue.

My question is, unless we're specifically blocking access from outside the reverse proxy server, aren't the pages still accessible directly using the subdomain, or specific server ip address?

Example:

```
www.Example.com/blog hosted in say our Florida datacenter
```

becomes

```
www.Example.com/blog     actually pointing to blog.Example.com hosted in say an Amazon EC2 cloud
```

Wouldn't a user still be able to access blog.Example.com directly unless we specify that we will only allow traffic from whatever the proxy server's IP address is?

I realize leaving access open to the world would introduce additional SEO considerations, but I can manage around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding a reverse proxy to the mix just adds another route in to the destination URL, it's much like adding a 301 redirect to a page doesn't mean traffic can't get in using other means.